# rust-libp2pのexampleのpingを模写して実行するとcargoが壊れる

Tags: rust, p2p

新規プロジェクトにexample pingのコードをコピーし、Cargo.tomlを以下のようにして実行したところ、プログラムが途中で強制終了し以下のエラーがでるようになってしまいました。

```
error: the 'cargo.exe' binary, normally provided by the 'cargo' component, is not applicable to the 'stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' toolchain
```

exampleを実行したときにはこのようなことが起こらなかったのでtomlファイルに何か記述が足りないのかと考えましたが、それがどれか分かりません。
原因が分かる方がいらっしゃいましたらお答頂けると幸いです。

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.3.14"
libp2p = "0.37.1"
```

OS: Windows10 Home
rustc: 1.52.0 stable
cargo: 1.52.0

libp2p example ping:
https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/blob/master/Cargo.toml

Comment: プロジェクトのディレクトリ構成はどうなっていますでしょうか？できればソースコード全体をGitHubに上げていただけると分かりやすいです。

Comment: 2021年5月10日に構成を変えずそのまま実行したところ、正常に動作するようになってしまいました・・・その後同様の問題は発生しておりません。
ソースコードをgithubに公開しました。
https://github.com/asobininn/lib2p2-ping-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 私の予想ですが、ネットワークのプログラムを実行する際にAvastによって何かが変更されてしまったのではないかと考えております。

エラーメッセージを確認したところ、rustupのプロキシーと呼ばれるプログラムが出したことがわかりました。

[rust-lang/rustup/src/toolchain.rs#L358-L361](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/blob/7a051f7f02075b54da58bf59d107b635518b1ba5/src/toolchain.rs#L358-L361)

```rust
if !component_status.available {
    return Err(anyhow!(format!(
        "the '{}' component which provides the command '{}' is not available for the '{}' toolchain",
        component_status.component.short_name(&manifest), binary_lossy, self.0.name)));
}
```

どうやらこのエラーはRustツールチェーンがインストール済みのステータスにもかかわらず、バイナリーファイル（今回は`cargo.exe`）が本来あるべき場所になかったときに起こるようです。

Windowsのことはよく知らないのですが、Avastというのはアンチウイルスソフトの一種でしょうか？　以下は仮説ですが、こんなことが起こったのかもしれません。

1. 質問者さまがネットワークのプログラムを実行するために`cargo run`コマンドを実行した
2. これにより`$Env:HOME\.cargo\bin\cargo.exe`バイナリーが実行される。が、実はこのバイナリーは`rustup`プロキシーで、`$Env:HOME\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin\cargo.exe`を起動するしくみになっている
3. `.rustup\toolchains\ ... \cargo.exe`が起動し、プログラムのコンパイル後に、コンパイルで生成されたバイナリーを起動した
4. そのバイナリーがlibp2pでネットーワークにアクセスしたところ、Avastがそれをウイルスによる活動だと誤認した
5. Avastが、そのバイナリーの親プロセスにあたる`.rustup\toolchains\ ... \cargo.exe`を実行できないようにした。（削除したか、安全な場所に隔離した）
6. 質問者さまが、もう一度、`cargo run`コマンドを実行した
7. `rustup`プロキシーが`.rustup\toolchains\ ... \cargo.exe`を起動しようとしたが、Avastによって実行できなくされていたため、ご質問のエラーが発生した

もしAvastに活動内容の記録があれば、それを見るともう少しはっきりするかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

私の予想ですが、ネットワークのプログラムを実行する際にAvastによって何かが変更されてしまったのではないかと考えております。